# General rule for converting between sigma and pi notation

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

What is the general rule for converting from $\Pi$ to $\sum$ notation?

Comment: You could use logs. For example, $$\prod_{i} a_i = e^{\ln \left(\prod\limits_{i} a_i \right)} = e^{\sum\limits_i \ln a_i},$$ if all $a_i > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a matter of "notation": $\Pi$ is for products and $\Sigma$ is for sums.  If each factor in the product is a sum of a few terms, you are expanding out the product: each choice of one of the terms in each factor gives you a term of the sum, and then you combine like terms.